# JavaScript instanceof operator returning false

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = new String("green");
    console.log(name instanceof String);//returns false
    var color= new String("green");
    console.log(color instanceof String);//returns true
```

Here the first one is returning false and the second one is returning true,what is the reason if i use variable as name it showing false
and are there are any variables like name which throws error as happened with variable name

Comment: reserve word's http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: `window.name` has a special meaning in JavaScript. It shouldn't be used as a global variable.

Comment: @JLRishe It's listed under *"JavaScript Objects, Properties, and Methods"*

Comment: @4castle Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Since `name` is reserved keywrd in javascript (not really reserved but global object), it directly points to `window.name`

you can try `_name` and it will work

```
var _name = new String("green");
console.log(_name instanceof String);//returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to overwrite the [global `name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name) variable, which has a setter that automatically converts anything you assign to it to a string (`new String` creates a `String` object, which is not the same as a string).

The solution: use a different variable name or properly scope your variables.

```js
console.log(typeof name); // string

var name = new String("green");

console.log(typeof name); // still string

var color = new String("green");

console.log(typeof color); // object

// create new scope
function myFunction() {
  var name = new String("green");

  console.log(typeof name); // object

  var color = new String("green");

  console.log(typeof color); // object
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

In the first case it checks the prototype chain find it undefined and return false. This is not only with `name` but following example will also return false

```
var simpleStr = 'This is a simple string'; 
console.log(simpleStr instanceof String);
```

An alternative way is to test it using `typeof` or `constructor`
The same example will return true for  the following case

```
var simpleStr = 'This is a simple string'; 
simpleStr .constructor == String
```

For your example also if you do

```
var name = new String("green");
name .constructor == String
```

it will return `true`

Comment: This question isn't a problem with OP's understanding of the `instanceof ` operator. OP is asking why it behaves differently on two variables that have both had `new String('...')` assigned to them.